# Lauterbach Trace32: No more arguments expected

Tags: trace, lauterbach

Sometimes while trying to view a memory through Lauterbach, I get the error "No more arguments expected" and I am unable to view memory. Why this happens and what is the resolution?

```
 d 0x83000000 /sl
 no more arguments expected
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error message "no more arguments expected" when you use more augments with a command than the command actually accepts. E.g.:

```
 Data.dump 0x83000000 /SpotLight 5
 Data.dump 0x83000000 0x42
 d 0x83000000 sl
```

However `d 0x83000000 /sl` seems not to contain a superfluous argument.
So either there is an **invisible character** - which can happen if you send the command via the remote API or you copy and paste the command from some editor - or there is a glitch in your version of TRACE32, in which you should contact the Lauterbach support.